Only bind QEMU's ports on localhost
I currently have a Debian server running at my home. I access it most of the time via SSH. It's running a few services, and to test some stuff, I've decided to run a QEMU virtual machine (also running Debian), that I can connect to with SSH only when I'm already connected to the host machine, so that I don't have to bother about security. However, I've found that QEMU also bound the port I use to SSH to my local network, which is bad because that machine has a very poorly secured password. How do I only bind ports on localhost?
The command I used to start the virtual machine is qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -boot d -m 2G -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 -net nic -nographic

as per man page : https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html
hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:10022-:22

(emphasis my)
hostfwd=[tcp|udp]:[hostaddr]:hostport-[guestaddr]:guestport


Redirect incoming TCP or UDP connections to the host port hostport to the guest IP address guestaddr on guest port guestport. If guestaddr is not specified, its value is x.x.x.15 (default first address given by the built-in DHCP server). By specifying hostaddr, the rule can be bound to a specific host interface. If no connection type is set, TCP is used. This option can be given multiple times.

